# Invoke-webrequest login & browse

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I can succesfully ignore certificate warning and log in to a website. However, I can not browse to another page $struggle. I am stuck at main page after log in. Anybody knows how to get raw content from pages after log in using the same websession? Thanks

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$myurl = "https://localhost/Portal";

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myurl -Method Get -SessionVariable mySession

$form = $response.Forms[0]

$form.Fields["DBUser"] = "user"
$form.Fields["DBPassword"] = "pass"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($myurl + $form.Action) -WebSession $mySession -Method Post -Body $form.Fields

$response.statusDescription

$struggle = "https://localhost/Portal/Dashboard.aspx?selection=1001"

$pagedownload = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($struggle) -WebSession $mySession
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Does the `$pagedownload` show that you are successfully logged in, as you seem suggest in your description?
If that is the issue, then I suggest having a look at the Network traffic when logging into your site using a browser, by using the netowrk console/debug function (`F12`) and see if getting "...?selection=101" relies on calling a javascript or similar. I've myself had issues with this, and have yet to find a successful workaround using IWR.

Comment: Yeah I think the javascript is also the issue. Must find another way.

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted your code based on how I've solved a similar issue

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$myurl = "https://localhost/Portal";

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myurl -Method Get

$form = $response.Forms[0]

$form.Fields["DBUser"] = "user"
$form.Fields["DBPassword"] = "pass"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($myurl + $form.Action) -SessionVariable mySession -Method Post -Body $form.Fields

$response.statusDescription

$struggle = "https://localhost/Portal/Dashboard.aspx?selection=1001"

$pagedownload = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($struggle) -SessionVariable mySession
```

The difference is that I always use `-SessionVariable` which takes a variable name, so no `$` is required. I also capture the session on you second `Invoke-WebRequest` upon the acquisition of the cookies/headers that I assume you want to use when accessing `$strugle`. If necessary adjust the code, to use the variable int he first invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the try but above code results in an exception:
`
Invoke-WebRequest : Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Portal./Default.aspx
`

Comment: This line causes the exception.

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($myurl + $form.Action) -SessionVariable mySession -Method Post -Body $form.Fields

Comment: Http status responses are dependent on your endpoints. Invoke-WebRequest is nothing more than the invoker. Just watchout if internal redirection happend. Put a Fiddler on and monitor what really happened.